# How to export contours created in scikit-image find_contours to shapefile or geojson?

Tags: python, arrays, contour, shapefile, scikit-image

I'm trying to export the results of the scikit-image.measure.find_contours() function as a shapefile or geojson after running on a satellite image.

The output is an array like (row, column) with coordinates along the contours, of which there are many.

How do I plot the coordinates of the various contours, and export this to a shapefile (can set appropriate projection etc.)?

My current code where 'mask' is my processed image:

```
from skimage import measure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

contours = measure.find_contours(mask, 0.5)

plt.imshow(mask)
for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
    plt.plot(contour[:,1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=1)
```

Comment: Given the question you asked yesterday, is `mask` a boolean array? If so, there might be a slightly more straightforward way of getting to the result you're looking for.

Comment: Yep - `mask` is a boolean array (as a result of thresholding).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following, adapted from a [post](https://sgillies.net/2014/01/18/getting-shapes-of-raster-features-with-rasterio.html) by the primary developer of `rasterio` and `fiona`, should work, though I'm sure you'll need to adapt a little more. It uses `rasterio.features.shapes` to identify contiguous regions in an image that have some value and return the associated coordinates, based on the transform of the raster. It then writes those records to a shapefile using `fiona`.

```
import fiona
import rasterio.features

schema = {"geometry": "Polygon", "properties": {"value": "int"}}

with rasterio.open(raster_filename) as raster:
    image = raster.read()
    # use your function to generate mask
    mask = your_thresholding_function(image)
    # and convert to uint8 for rasterio.features.shapes
    mask = mask.astype('uint8')
    shapes = rasterio.features.shapes(mask, transform=raster.transform)
    # select the records from shapes where the value is 1,
    # or where the mask was True
    records = [{"geometry": geometry, "properties": {"value": value}}
               for (geometry, value) in shapes if value == 1]
    with fiona.open(shape_filename, "w", "ESRI Shapefile",
                    crs=raster.crs.data, schema=schema) as out_file:
        out_file.writerecords(records)
```

---

Comment: This works with very few changes. Using `rasterio.open()` instead of my original `gdal.Open()` is fine as I can go straight into any image manipulation on the array (thresholding and a few other steps).

Adding `mask = np.invert(mask)` just before `rasterio.features.shapes` allows me to pull out the inverse regions (useful for me in this case).

Comment: I guess my example doesn't integrate the plotting part of your question. You could take a look at this question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193653/plot-shapefile-on-top-of-raster-using-plot-and-imshow-from-matplotlib) about plotting a shapefile on a raster in python.

Answer (score 2):

simply use skimage:

`from skimage.draw import polygon2mask
mask = polygon2mask(image_shape, contours[i])`

i is the index of the contour you want to plot overlaying your original image of dimension image_shape.

Comment: This approach will create polygons which will not give correct results always because contours are not always polygons and it will always create polygons.

Answer (score 0):

You should install python library `geojson` and work with that.

In order to play with the coordinates and mark objects present in the image you should use the library `shapely`.

Answer (score 0):

@Cate you could use those `row, column` coordinate matrices and plot them via http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon (filled polygon), http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.polygon_perimeter (only perimeter), or create your custom polygon plotting function on top of http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon.

Comment: Thanks @soupault, trying to get this working within the nested list structure that `find_contours()` puts out. With each polygon as a sublist would you create a shapefile and append to it as you iterate through the list, or is there an easy way to write them all at once?

Comment: @Cate sorry, I'm not familiar with the mentioned formats (shapefile, geojson). I think you should take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geojson and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp. Perhaps, the functionality you are looking for is already there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my recipe and it works quite well.

```
import skimage
import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import shapely
import fiona

#Open raster with gdal
image=gdal.Open('A.tif')
im=image.ReadAsArray()

#out variable stores the contours
out=skimage.measure.find_contours(im,0.5)
# Here,0.5 is taken  assuming it is a binary raster
# but the default value is taken as (np.max(im)+np.min(im))/2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(im, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
#cs list will contain all the 2D Line objects
cs=[]
for contour in out:
    cs.append(ax.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2))

ax.axis('image')
#Show image with contours
plt.show()

#Read band 1 of raster or as per the usage it can be tweaked
with rasterio.open('A.tif') as raster:
    image = raster.read()[0,:,:]
    
#Create list poly containing all the linestrings of contours
from shapely.geometry import mapping,MultiLineString,LineString
poly=[]
for i in cs:
    
    x=i[0].get_xdata()
    y=i[0].get_ydata()
    aa=rasterio.transform.xy(raster.transform,y,x)
    poly.append(LineString([(i[0], i[1]) for i in zip(aa[0],aa[1])]))

#Create a list of wkt strings
list_lstrings =  [shapely.wkt.loads(p.wkt) for p in poly]
# Create a MultiLineString object from the list
mult=shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(list_lstrings)

#Inputting projection info
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
crs = from_epsg(4326)

#Create schema    
schema = {
    'geometry': 'MultiLineString',
    'properties': {'id': 'int'},
}

# Write a new Shapefile
with fiona.open('U:\\new_shape.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema,crs=crs) as c:
    
    c.write({
        'geometry': mapping(mult),
        'properties': {'id': 1},
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more solution, for converting the output of `skimage.measure.find_contours` to a shapefile using [pyshp](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/):

```py
import shapefile
import skimage.measure

contours = skimage.measure.find_contours(mask, 0.5)
points = []
parts = []
for loop in contours:
    parts.append(len(points))
    points.extend(geo_loop)
shape = shapefile.Shape(
    shapeType=shapefile.POLYGON, points=points, parts=parts)

with shapefile.Writer(output_shapefile,
                      shapeType=shapefile.POLYGON) as w:
    w.field('Field', 'C')
    w.record('polygon_id')
    w.shape(shape)
```